# How to restrict UIPopoverController for Portrait orientation only?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am developing an iPad application which is using camera functionality. I am opening camera into UIPopoverController. My application supports only portrait orientation and i want to restrict UIPopoverController also to be support portrait orientation only.

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

For restricting ur app to be viewed in portrait mode, set this one....

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return NO;
}
```

Set `return NO` in all classes...:)

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIPopoverController's object instance. Hide and unhide whenever orientation changes.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   if ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
   {
         // hidden your popover
   }
   return YES;
}
```